# How to use a dedicated thread to receive UDP data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp, asio

I would like to use a dedicated thread to receive udp data using asio library. An example code is given below.

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE // we are using the stand aloe version of ASIO and Not Boost::ASIO


#include <iostream>
#include "include/asio.hpp"
#include <array>
#include <thread>


class UDPServer
{

public:
    UDPServer( asio::io_service& ioService): m_socket(ioService)
    {}
    ~UDPServer(){}

    void listen(const int& port)
    {
        m_socket.open(asio::ip::udp::v4());
        m_socket.bind(asio::ip::udp::endpoint(asio::ip::udp::v4(), port));

#define DEDICATED_THREAD_FLAG  1

#if DEDICATED_THREAD_FLAG
        m_thread = std::thread( &UDPServer::receive, this);
        std::cout<<"Thead Id in listen:"<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
        m_thread.join();
#else
        receive();
#endif
    }

    template<std::size_t SIZE>
    void processReceivedData(const std::array<char, SIZE>& rcvdMessage,
                             const int& rcvdMessageSizeInBytes,
                             const std::error_code& error)
    {

        std::cout<<"Rcvd Message: "<<rcvdMessage.data()<<std::endl;
        receive();

    }
    void receive()
    {
        std::cout<<"Thead Id in receive0:"<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;

        asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_udpRemoteEndpoint;

        m_socket.async_receive_from(asio::buffer(recv_buffer, recv_buffer.size()/*NetworkBufferSize*/), m_udpRemoteEndpoint,
                                    [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t bytesReceived)
        {
            std::cout<<"Thead Id in receive1:"<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;

            processReceivedData(recv_buffer, bytesReceived, ec);
        });

    }

private:
    asio::ip::udp::socket m_socket;
    std::thread m_thread;
    static const int NetworkBufferSize = 9000;
    std::array<char, NetworkBufferSize> recv_buffer;

};


int main()
{

    std::cout<<"Main Thead Id:"<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
    asio::io_service m_ioService;


    UDPServer myServer( m_ioService);
    myServer.listen(12345); // starting the UDP server

    std::cout<<"Program waiting.."<<std::endl;

    m_ioService.run();


    std::cout<<"Program ending.."<<std::endl;
}
```

A non dedicated thread version can be enable by changing DEDICATED_THREAD_FLAG to 0, which is working as expected.

However, when DEDICATED_THREAD_FLAG is set to 1, a new thread is starting and entering the "receive" function. But when a udp packet arrives, it is handled by only the main thread and not by the dedicated thread.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole event-loop that handles the asynchronous calls is done by the `io_server`, which you run in the main thread.

Instead of running the `receive` function in the thread (it will return immediately anyway), you should run `io_service::run`.

Comment: Can you please help with the modified code so that I can try it? My efforts towards it are not working!

Comment: @Soo Simplest way? How about `std::thread th(&asio::io_service::run, m_ioService);`?

Comment: The above code resulted in an error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, asio::io_service&)’
                                                                             ^

Comment: @Soo Ah yes, it have overloads. So just use a lambda that captures the service and calls its `run` function?

Comment: Can you please provide a piece of working code for the same?

Comment: @Soo You already use lambdas with captures in the code you show. Did you not write it? Did you just copy it? Please don't fall into the trap of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Oh, I was thinkning about something complicated and it turned out that a simple lambda function to call "m_ioService.run()" solved the issue. Thanks